# Rails namespace with path name different than module name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'd like to have a namespace in Rails where the module name in code is different than the path name that user sees in the URL.

One can make a namespace in routes like so:

```
namespace :admin_ui do
  resources :posts
end
```

and this will match /admin_ui/posts to `AdminUI::PostsController`.

How can I make this namespace match the path /admin, but use module `AdminUI`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it:

```
namespace :admin_ui, path: 'admin' do
  resources :posts
end
```